# Ember Run Loop in testing mode

Tags: javascript, ember.js, runloop, ember-testing

I'm using https://github.com/ride/ember-stripe-service add-on and everything worked nicely until `Ember 1.10.1`, but since `Ember 1.11.0` Ember's run loop start crashing in E2E testing saying that we were trying to access a destroyed object, I have been trying to fix it but I couldn't so I made a PR https://github.com/ride/ember-stripe-service/pull/32 reproducing the error in `tests/dummy` and `tests/integration` but neither they know how to fix it, please help.

We think is something related with Stripe.js (https://js.stripe.com/v2/) because they embed an Iframe when the script in loaded in the browser.